# How to force open PDF in particular view?

Tags: pdf, browser, acrobat

I have few questions about it:

How to force pdf brochure open in particular view in browser? Is it possible? If not, how to do it in Acrobat Reader DC?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not all PDF viewers, in-browser or otherwise, respect the "Initial View" settings. However, Acrobat Reader does. You can set the initial view, including page number, zoom level, page layout, and turn on or off some of the UI elements using the Initial View tab in the Document Properties dialog in the Acrobat Standard. Save the file with these properties and Acrobat Reader (and a few others) will respect them.

[image]